# Raspberry Pi 4 with Pi2SCART

Tags: video, retropie, pi-4

I've recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 that I intend to connect to an old TV with SCART connector to do some sweet old retro gaming. For that purpose, I bought a Pi2SCART adaptator. I've followed the instructions for the installation so I added this to config.txt :

```
disable_audio_dither=1
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=vga666
enable_dpi_lcd=1
display_default_lcd=1
dpi_group=2
dpi_mode=87
hdmi_timings=320 1 16 30 34 240 1 2 3 22 0 0 0 60 0 6400000 1 #240p
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Have anyone done this kind of configuration ?

Comment: When you added these config parameters, did you check for conflicting lines?. E.g. isn't there another line in `config.txt` that reads `dpi_group=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's silly but the problem was not from the software...but the hardware ! The SCART cable I had was broken.